# Is there any native way on windows or using sysinternals to scan what websites a process is accessing?

Tags: windows-10, networking, sysinternals

I am struggling to find a way to scan for websites an specific process on windows 10 os is accessing without having to get a commercial tool or without a full package tracing app like wireshark

I was hoping ProcessExplorer from systools would do that but it doesn't have such feature. thanks

Comment: Try Nirsoft.net , Browsing History View and see if that helps.

Answer (score 0):

TCPView, from Microsoft Sysinternals.
https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/tcpview